# JCOP Shell does not output prompts

Tags: javacard, jcop

I was working on an Applet of JCOP on Eclipse. But all of a sudden, no matter how I clean and try to create new projects, the JCOP Shell (JCShell) will selectively omit some outputs for commands sent in. I don't know what is wrong. And there does not seem to be any manual related to how I can set up JCShell.

Is there any commands or preference settings to make JCOP Shell reverse to the standard settings?

[image: JCOP Shell]

Comment: What outputs do you miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to receive full information, you should enable **Trace APDUs** and **Comm details** options:

[image]

Comment: I turned on **Trace APDUs**, and it works!! XD An odd thing is, I don’t see **Comm details** button, or the button on the right of **Trace APDUs** as in your screenshot.

Comment: I am using *3.1.2* in Eclipse Juno on a 32-bit Windows machine. Can I know the version number of the latest version?